# How can I read explicit https proxy CA certificate on RHEL7?

Tags: proxy, certificate-authority, rhel7

I have server behind explicit https proxy with SSL decryption but I don't know its certificate and I have no way to obtain it from human being. Is it possible to retrieve https proxy certificate from server CLI so that I could add it as trusted CA?

It's RHEL 7 so as far as I know there's no openssl 1.1.x (which supports -proxy parameter and allows to do that)

Answer (score 0):

Since about spring 2020, there is the `openssl11` command in the same-named RPM package available in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) 7 repository, which supports the `-proxy` parameter at `openssl11 s_client`.